# how do I select all columns of the last row in each group in DolphinDB database?

Tags: dolphindb

I have a table of roughly 100 columns and would like to select all columns of the last row in each (symbol,date) group. The only way that I can work out is

```
select last(column1), last(column2), ... , last(column100) from t context by symbol, date
```

Is there a simpler way? It's not realistic to write down all 100 column names.

Answer (score 0):

The context by clause can work together with having clause in DolphinDB

```
select * from t context by symbol, date having rowNo(symbol) = size(symbol) - 1
```